# What does 'field declared dynamically' mean in this situation?

Tags: php, oop, phpstorm

I'm pretty new to OOP and PHP. I'm using the IDE PhpStorm and it's giving me this (see below) warning on my reference to `$width`.

[image: Warning 'Field declared dynamically']

Here is my code:

```
<?php
class box {
    private $width;

    function __construct(){
        $this->width = 3;
    }
}
?>
```

I've never seen the term "field" used before, and I'm not entirely sure what the sentence "Field declared dynamically" means.

It seems like this warning just showed up today after I updated PhpStorm. Did I do something wrong?

Also, if anyone can briefly explain what the warning means by "Note: Check is not performed on objects of type "stdClass" or derived"?

Comment: look at [this](http://blog.pepa.info/php-html-css/tools/template-undefined-field-warnings-in-phpstorm/)

Comment: Thanks Félix, this should help a lot! :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please do **`File | Invalidate Caches...`** and restart IDE -- your indexes seems to be corrupted/out-of-date after update.

---

> and I'm not entirely sure what the sentence "Field declared dynamically" means.

This means that the field/property is not explicitly declared but relies on `__get()` and `__set()` magic methods to have it working.

In your case you do have field declared properly (the `private $width;` part) -- it's just an IDE glitch that quite often happens after IDE gets updated to newer version.

---

> Also, if anyone can briefly explain what the warning means by "Note: Check is not performed on objects of type "stdClass" or derived"?

It means exactly that: this check is not performed if the object is an instance of `stdClass` or extends such class.

This is because of the nature of `stdClass` -- it can accept calls to any fields (even undefined -- it will silently define it for you during runtime) and will not throw the errors that usual classes would in such cases.